# A fair die is rolled eight times. What is the probability of getting exactly 2 threes, exactly 3 ones, and exactly 2 sixes?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, permutations, combinations

I was given the following hint:

*Break the task of counting the desirable outcomes into three subtasks:*

- (a) choose the location of the extra non-three, one, or six in the sequence of eight throws,
- (b) permute the seven threes, ones, and sixes, and
- (c) choose a non-three, one, or six to occupy the location determined in subtask (a).

However, I am confused by this hint. From my understanding, in order to combine these three tasks, I would do:

$$8 \times (2!) \times  (2!) \times  (2!) \times \frac{\left(\frac 12\right)^8}{8!}$$

because there are 8 possible locations for the extra non-three, one, or six; the permutations of the threes, ones, and sixes are $2!, 2!$, and $3!$; and the probability of not rolling a one, three, or six 8 times is $\left(\frac 12\right)^8$. But this doesn't seem correct for some reason. Disregarding the hint, I would approach the problem by doing the following:

$$8 \times \left(\frac 16\right)^7 x \left(\frac 56\right)$$

I can't really tell which approach is correct, because I'm having a really hard time visualizing this problem.

Comment: It is often very helpful to write down several examples of the outcomes of the procedure you are trying to count.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Record the outcome of the rolling as a string of length $8$, made  of symbols chosen from $\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$. There are $6^8$ such strings, all **equally likely** if the die is fair and rolled fairly.

Now we count the number of good strings, where good means fitting the specifications in the title.

The **location** of the digit which is different from $3$, $1$, or $6$ can be chosen in $8$ ways. For each choice of location, there are $3$ ways to choose which one of the three possibilities the  "odd" digit will be. Thus there are $(8)(3)$ ways to decide on the location and type of the "odd" digit.

For every way of doing the above two tasks, there are $7$ empty slots. There are $\frac{7!}{2!3!2!}$ ways of filling them with two $3$'s, three $1$'s, and two $6$'s. That gives a total of $(8)(3)\left(\frac{7!}{2!3!2!}\right)$ good strings. Divide by $6^8$ for the probability.

We can count the number of ways of filling the $7$ slots more slowly. The location of the $3$'s can be chosen in $\binom{7}{2}$ ways. For each of thse choices, the location of the $1$'s can be chosen in $\binom{5}{3}$ ways, for a total of $\binom{7}{2}\binom{5}{3}$. That gives the expression $(8)(3)\binom{7}{2}\binom{5}{3}$ for the number of good strings.

**Remark:** There are other ways to organize the count. For example, let us make an $8$-letter string, made up of two $3$'s, three $1$'s, two $6$'s, and an $x$, to act as a placeholder for the "odd" number. There are $\frac{8!}{2!3!2!}$ ways to do this. Multiply by $3$, because $x$ can be replaced by any of $3$ values.

Answer (score 1):

Let $D_k$ be the event that the die turns up $k$. Let $D_{i_1}, D_{i_2}, \cdots D_{i_k}$ denote the event that the first roll turns up $i_1$,the second $i_2$, etc.

First compute $D_3 D_3 D_1 D_1 D_1 D_6 D_6 D_k$, where $k \in \{ 2, 4, 5\}$. The probability of this specific event for a particular $k$ is $\frac{1}{6^8}$, and the combined probability of the (mutually exclusive) events for $k \in \{ 2, 4, 5\}$ is given by $3 \frac{1}{6^8}$.

Now see how we can rearrange the events. First select the positions for the 3's, there are $\binom{8}{2}$ possibilities. Now select the 1's, there are $\binom{6}{3}$ possibilities, and finally select the 6's, there are $\binom{3}{2}$ possibilities. Note that $\binom{8}{2} \binom{6}{3} \binom{3}{2} = \frac{8!}{2!\, 3!\, 2!}$.

Hence the answer is $3 \frac{1}{6^8} \frac{8!}{2!\, 3!\, 2!} = \frac{35}{11664}$.